# Meta property on pdf files?

Tags: facebook, pdf, properties, media, meta

So I am trying to create share buttons for certain files, like pdf, images or videos. Unfortunately, when I share the public URL of the document, FB does not show any image or title of the document.

How do I get around this? Is the only solution to create another html page with the meta properties in them?

Comment: That, or using the Feed dialog to share.

Comment: How do you set it up? Is it like a share button with html?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog